# How to compute the change of coordinate functions

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, projective-geometry, projective-space

Let $ n \in \mathbb{N}$ be an integer ,$  n\geq 1$ and let $ M = P ( \mathbb{R}^{n+1})$ denote the real projective space  of dimension n. Let $(x_0,...,x_n)$ the coordinates on $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ we use the $n+1$ we use the $n+1$ coordinate  charts $\psi_i : O_i \subseteq \mathbb{ R}^n \to U_i$ given by

$\psi_i ( x_0,...,x_{i-1} , x_{i+1} ,...,x_n) = \mathbb{R} ( x_0,..., x_{i-1} ,1 , x_{i+1} ,
...,x_n)$.

Compute the change of coordinates functions $\psi^{-1}_i \circ \psi_j $ for $i<j$.

$\psi_{i}^{-1} ( r x_0,..., rx_{i-1} ,r, rx_{i+1} ,..., rx_n) = ( x_0,...,x_{i-1}, x_{i+1},...,x_n)$.

But by this inverse formula:  $\psi^{-1}_i \circ \psi_j $ doesn't make sense.

Can you please help me compute this  change of coordinates functions? This type of questions of computing change of coordinate functions  occurs many times.

Comment: Why do you think $\psi_i^{-1}\circ\psi_j$ doesn't make sense? I will note that it is not defined on all of $O_j$. Is that your concern?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese because the range of $\psi_j \neq$  domain of  $\psi_i^{-1}$  according to my definition of $\psi^{-1}_i$ . I think I am not able to define $\psi^{-1}_i$ is.

Comment: Like I said, it's not defined on all of $O_j$, but there is a perfectly well-defined map $\psi_i^{-1}\circ\psi_j : \psi_j^{-1}(U_i\cap U_j) \to \psi_i^{-1}(U_i\cap U_j)$.